# Find a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, permutations

For $x = (12)(34)$ and $y = (56)(13),$ find a permutation $a$ such that $a^{-1}xa = y$.

I written $a^{-1}xa = y$ as $xa = ay$ thus $(12)(34)a = a(56)(13)$ but I can't find the $a$?

Answer (score 1):

Conjugation affects cycles like so: $\sigma(a_1~a_2~\cdots~a_r)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(a_1)~\sigma(a_2)~\cdots~\sigma(a_r))$.

So, how does conjugation affect a permutation's disjoint cycle representation?

Comment: Anon I still don't know how to solve this problem. Can you explain it more please?

Comment: And this chapter was before conjugacy, so I don't think we can apply that here.

Comment: @user104235 If you're not allowed to talk about conjugation, even without using the word "conjugation," then you're not allowed to do the problem at all, plain and simple, because the problem is *about* a particular conjugation. The reason I ask questions in my answers is so that people can come to understand problems in multiple stages (rather than just doing the whole thing for others). However you have not told me any of your thoughts on the pedagogical question I posed, so I don't know where I need to break the problem up into simpler steps.

Comment: In particular: (1) do you understand what I've said so far? (2) can you extrapolate to figure out how conjugation explicitly affects a *product* of (disjoint) cycles? (3) so then (rearranging $a^{-1}xa=y$ $\Leftrightarrow x=aya^{-1}$) what does $a(56)(13)a^{-1}$ look like? and finally (4) what can you select $a$ to be to achieve $(12)(34)$?

Comment: $a^{-1}(12)(34)a = (56)(13)$. I am stuck in finding such an a.

Comment: When I say "what does [this conjugation] look like," *right* after explaining how conjugations look explicitly, I expect you to *use* the information I give you!

Comment: I took the time to use your hint and I used an explicit example to help for reference but I still have no luck in finding such an a that will work. You said, from your answer, I can write the conjugations affecting my cycles as $a(x_1)..a(x_r)$ but I don't see how to use that to find my a.

Comment: $$(\color{Red}{1}\color{Blue}{2})(\color{Green}{3}\color{Purple}{4})=a(56)(13) a^{-1}=\big( \color{Red}{a(5)} \color{Blue}{a(6)} \big) \big( \color{Green}{a(1)} \color{Purple}{a(3)} \big)$$